# ob_gzhandler and memcached causing encoding error with headers

Tags: php, http, http-headers, memcached, gzip

I know that there is a lot of stuff out there about ob_gzhandler with memcached and headercodes but I cant seem to find the right solution for me.

Whenever there is a custom headercode I keep getting encoding errors. I tried the following to avoid this problem but still no luck. I cant seem to be able to send headercodes and use ob_gzhandler. Since I've implemented memcached long after building the initial site(s) I use ob_start to "grab" the output and set it to memcached. I especially use this a lot for homepages which I can buffer fully since most of them don't really have dynamic content.

Is it possible to set ob_gzhandler and still send headercodes or should I only start a ob_gzhandler when no custom headercodes are send?

Comment: Could you give some example code that not working?

Comment: I think you can use ob_gzhandler before any output is done. Headers don't count as output, so I think sould work.  You could run in problems if the pages you are tryiing to pass trought ob_gzhandler are already doing some ob_handler stuff, or somewhere theres a trailing space leaking before of your code, aborting headers. ob_gzhandlers probably need to set his own headers, so if can't use headers (because theres arleady some output) can't work.